# how to add a css class to a list when the particular li is clicked using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried to addClass when one among the li is clicked.But i am unable to toggle the class.I mean if another li is clicked ,the css which we before added to befor li is not getting disappered..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-masthead li a').on('click', function() {
    $('#nav-masthead li a').removeClass("col");
    $(this).addClass("col");
  });
});
```

```css
.col {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="padding-top: 38px;padding-left:113px">
  <li class="nav nav-tabs">
    <a href="#/Home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home ">Home</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#/Add"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign ">Add Form</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#/View">View Form</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your code should work assuming that parent `ul` has `id=nav-masthead`. Please check any console errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of bits incorrect in both your HTML and your JS.

Your HTML does not have the id `#nav-masthead` which is what the JS function is looking for so I've now added that in to the `ul`.

You are also not preventing the default functionality of an `a` click which will do a redirect. I have disabled this as obviously the change in class will not impact the view for the user as they are being redirected.

I've also made the change of colors a bit more obvious to show how it all works but you can amend the CSS to your liking.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-masthead li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#nav-masthead li a').removeClass("col");
    $(this).addClass("col");
  });
});
```

```css
#nav-masthead li a {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
#nav-masthead li a.col {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav-masthead" style="padding-top: 38px;padding-left:113px">
  <li class="nav nav-tabs">
    <a href="#/Home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home ">Home</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#/Add"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign ">Add Form</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#/View">View Form</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `window.location.href` :

```
$("#nav-masthead li a").each(function()
{
    if(this.href==window.location.href)
    {
       $(this).addClass('col');
       $(this).removeAttr('href'); //optional
    }
 });
```

Comment: can you please explain what is exactly you are doing?

Comment: I'm simply click on the following link, and check this.href with what url you are visit right now, if match both I add following class on the link element

Comment: have you read the question properly? OP is not able to remove previously added class and I did not see anything to remove class in your code.

Comment: when you click on the link it will refresh the page, then the class that recently added will remove automatic

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had once faced the same issue and I found this solution, hope this solves your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav-masthead li a').on('click', function() {
        var elm = $(this);
        $('#nav-masthead').find('a').each(function(n,e){
            $(e).removeClass("col");
        });
        elm.addClass("col");
    });
});
```